# nginx proxy pass ip from url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have multiple web servers with IP address say 172.18.1.1 to 172.18.1.20, hosting different website on 443(https) and A nginx server which I need to use for proxying above servers.

**Example :**
My nginx server IP is https://10.220.5.39:9200 by giving web server in URL , I need to show the websites

i.e. https://10.220.5.39:9200/proxy/172.18.1.1, should get website of https://172.18.1.1

AND

https://10.220.5.39:9200/proxy/172.18.1.2, should get website of https://172.18.1.2

```
location /proxy/(?<uniqueId>[^/]+).* {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass    https://$uniqueId/;
}
```

But it is not working , I can not use redirect , since client will not have access to web servers directly

Also some website use css file from route i.e. `href="/static/theme.css"`

because of which in browser console we are getting

```
not found https://10.220.5.39:9200/static/theme.css
```

Is this even possible with nginx

Comment: did you check  the access `https://172.18.1.2`

Comment: Yes , I am able to access `https://172.18.1.2` from machine 10.220.5.39.